# Import feed to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Trying, for funsies, to make Google Spreadsheet read comments from FaceBook. I have discovered that FaceBook actually uses an API for this, and I've been [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10154571359113051%2Fcomments%3Ffields%3Dfrom%2Cmessage%2Ccreated_time%26limit%3D99999999&version=v2.3) and made the code to actually export it in a manner I find most convenient. Now I just need to make Google Spreadsheet *somehow* read it.. My first thought was to use the different import ways they have (IMPORTXML, IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML and IMPORTRANGE). The IMPORTRANGE is a quite obvious no go in my book, and so far I've had no success with the other ones. Am I still too far off importing it, or is there hope? If I get the code a cURL I can just use a (really) long string in my web browser and get something I can surely extract data from, though I would only be able to do it locally, the goal with this is that it will be set globally so to speak.

Comment: If you hard code a URL that access token will stop working after a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using "[How to import JSON data into Google Spreadsheets in less than 5 minutes](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a#.px1h1jase%22How%20to%20import%20JSON%20data%20into%20Google%20Spreadsheets%20in%20less%20than%205%20minutes%22)", it instructed me to make a custom script in my sheets and paste [this script](https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164) in it including the generated text, and then simply use the new formula "ImportJSON". Worked like a treat :D Do I just delete this post or simply keep it as is?.. Still kinda fresh to Stack Overflow :P

Comment: Hi @Sodori. Can you please share your script here?